# Calculate % of filtered values from all values in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have this pivot table that currently shows how many students failed in a particular subject in a particular academic year. That is, it is now filtered by Pass_Status Fail(which can be either Pass or Fail):

Photo attached [image: Here]

For example, in Business Computing subject there were 3 people in 2002-2003, and two of them failed. That is what the table shows right now.

But I want to convert it into percentage, considering the number of all the students who took the subject in an academic year as total.

In the case of Business Computing in 2002-2003, I want to show 66% (2 failed of 3).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on any value of the "GrandTotal" column, then select "value Field Settings". You can see a tab there named as "Show value As". Select that.

You will have a drop down list, with no calculation. Now open the drop-down list, to select '% of grand total" or '% of parent total" or whatever the way you want.

Hope it helps.